# how to ng-model in ng-repeat?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

How to get the selected items if you choose  more than one link, for example, I choose the USA and Can, Fra, Ger, China ... So how can I get the selected items from the `ng-model`?

The `view` is below:

```
   <div class="layer-box picker-box toggle-box get-value" id="picker-filter-country">
        <div class="list-header"><a href="#" class="layer-close icon-close">X</a><span class="t">country</span></div>
        <input type="search" autocomplete="off" class="box-search" name="searchcountry" ng-model="searchcountry">
        <a href="#" data-val="{{country.key}}" class="item"  ng-repeat="country in territories | filter:searchcountry " ng-model="country.name">{{country.name}}</a>

        <a class="layerbutton t" ng-click="search()">done</a>
    </div>
```

How can I get the results like `$scope.(name of ng-model)` in the controller? It doesn't work if I obtain them by `$scope.country.name`.

PS: It will create a list of countries in the form of links, if you click one, it will be choosen...

Comment: it should be an array

Comment: so how can i do? @harish

Answer (score 0):

please have a look to : [PLUNKER](http://plnkr.co/edit/w8LYzpYY9hsXZLxe3q87)

```
<select multiple ng-model="selectedValues">
    <option value="1">Blue</option>
    <option value="2">Green</option>
    <option value="3">Yellow</option>
    <option value="4">Red</option>
</select>
```

and js code

```
    $scope.selectedValues = [];
```

Comment: sorry,may be i missed the important piece of code:                              <a href="#" data-val="{{country.key}}" class="item"  ng-repeat="country in territories | filter:searchcountry " ng-model="country.name">{{country.name}}</a>

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I think I understand your question.

In your `views`, try passing the parameter of the `ng-model` of your selected country into your search function, refer to the example below.

```
<a class="layerbutton t" ng-click="search(country.name)">done</a>
```

Comment: yeap,i have implemented your method,but i just want to get the selected items by just a bingding ng-model,am i clear?